# Unix Sed Escape Single Quote

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have file data as below

1. `bill johnson`
2. `robert dylan`
3. `neil o'bryan`

and the requirement is to extract the last name and add @mail.com to it. I used the below command

```
cut -d"|" -f2 emp.lst | sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \([a-z][a-z]*\)/\2@mail.com/'
```

-- Cut command to get the second field from the file (full name)
-- Sed to separate first and last name and assign email to the last name

Everything works fine except the name `neil o'bryan` and below is the result I got

1. `johnson@mail.com`
2. `dylan@gmail.com`
3. `o@gmail.com'bryan`

Please help me how to get the name with single quote work as expected. i.e. o'bryan@mail.com

Comment: `awk '{printf "%s\n", $2"@mail.com"}' file` (or `$3` if the lines are actually numbered)...

Comment: You are using `cut -d"|"` but your data file has no `|` characters in it.  Explain.

Comment: Do you think `\([a-z][a-z]*\)` could possible match `o'bryan`? :)

Comment: Its not a possible match. I am not sure how to include single quote here to match o'bryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `o'brian` should be `obrian` in the email address, just add a `tr` stage to the pipeline to get rid of unwanted characters:

```
cut -d "|" -f2 emp.lst |
tr -d "'" |
sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \([a-z][a-z]*\)/\2@mail.com/'
```

You could do the same with any other characters you'd like to remove, or convert to something else, like

```
cut -d "|" -f2 emp.lst |
tr -d "'" |
tr 'åäöé' 'aaoe' |
sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \([a-z][a-z]*\)/\2@mail.com/'
```

If the address should be `o'brian@mail.com` (with the apostrophe in place), just add that to the regular expression:

```
cut -d "|" -f2 emp.lst |
sed "s/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \([a-z]['a-z]*\)/\2@mail.com/"
```

Comment: @Nathan Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).